# Building a networking event system, what data format should I use?

Tags: actionscript-3, node.js, tcp

I'm using Node.js to build an event based game server (to a flash client). But, I'm having trouble finding examples of how I should architect this message passing.

To simplify things, I was thinking in using a json:

```
{signature: 'event_name', { /* event data /*} }
```

So I can easily write to socket using any serialization library. Is it a good idea? Please point me to articles, tutorials or books if you think I don't know what I'm doing at all (which I think is the case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format). There is a pure javascript version of it: http://www.jamesward.com/2010/07/07/amf-js-a-pure-javascript-amf-implementation/

Answer (score 0):

[BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) is what you are looking for, it has similar properties to JSON, but it a lot smaller and faster to parse. The [MongoDB driver for node](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/index.html) has a BSON library in it, I don't know about any Flash librarys though.